# dataGridView Context menu function

Tags: c#

I have added this code to my forum:

```
    private void dataGridView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            ContextMenu a = new ContextMenu();
            a.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Google"));
            a.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Yahoo"));
            int currentMouseOverRow = dataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).RowIndex;
            if (currentMouseOverRow >= 0)
            {
                a.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem(string.Format("", currentMouseOverRow.ToString())));
            }
            a.Show(dataGridView1, new Point(e.X, e.Y));
        }
    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellMouseEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        currentMouseOverRow = e.RowIndex;
    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellMouseLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        currentMouseOverRow = -1;
    }
```

But how do I add the function to the context menu option?

For google,

```
    Process.Start("https://www.google.com");
```

For yahoo,

```
    Process.Start("https://www.yahoo.com");
```

etc.

Comment: Do you mean when one of the ContextMenu item is clicked say Google?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not add your `ContextMenu` right when your Form `loads` rather than every time that the user right click your `DataGridView` which means that you have to add the `Context Menu` every time the user rights click your `DatGridView`.

Secondly, instead of `ContextMenu` make a `ContextMenuStrip` instead which more at home with `DataGridView`. So, your code would look like:

```
ContextMenuStrip a = new ContextMenuStrip();

public Form1()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   this.Load += new EventHandler(Form1_Load);
}

void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Image img = null;
   a.Items.Add("Google", img, new System.EventHandler(ContextMenuClick));
   a.Items.Add("Yahoo", img, new System.EventHandler(ContextMenuClick));
   dataGridView1.ContextMenuStrip = a;
}
```

Then your `EventHandler` would look like this:

```
private void ContextMenuClick(Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
 {
   switch (sender.ToString().Trim())
    {
      case "Google":
        Process.Start("https://www.google.com");
        break;
      case "Yahoo":
        Process.Start("https://www.yahoo.com");
        break;
    }
 }
```

And your `DataGridView` `Mouse Click` handler would look this:

```
void dataGridView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
 {
   if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
     {
       int currentMouseOverRow = dataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).RowIndex;
       if (currentMouseOverRow >= 0)
         {
           a.Items.Add(string.Format("", currentMouseOverRow.ToString()));
         }
       a.Show(dataGridView1, new Point(e.X, e.Y));
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `ClickEvent` for your menu items:

```
//menu items constructor
a.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Google", new System.EventHandler(this.MenuItemClick)));
a.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Yahoo", new System.EventHandler(this.MenuItemClick)));

private void MenuItemClick(Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
     var m = (MenuItem)sender;

     if (m.Text == "Google")
     {
         Process.Start("https://www.google.com");
     }
}
```

Comment: Can you check if `m.Text == "Google"`? Cause maybe I used wrong property to compare? :/

Comment: Then the only reason why it is not working I can come up with is that you have not set default browser in your system and process start can't find a program to fire. I used that method so many times and it always worked :)

Comment: Well I will try again, but I'm quite sure I've done it right.